# If I am sending data from python how do I receive in matlab side all these?

Tags: python, matlab

Here I have a python server:

```py
import pygds as g 
import time 
d = g.GDS() 
minf_s = sorted(d.GetSupportedSamplingRates()[0].items())[0] 
d.SamplingRate, d.NumberOfScans = minf_s 
for ch in d.Channels:
    ch.Acquire = True 
d.SetConfiguration() 
scope = g.Scope(1/d.SamplingRate)
#print("test")
# data = d.GetData(d.SamplingRate,scope)
# this runs the scope figure
#data = d.GetData(d.SamplingRate)
        
        
        
        
data = d.GetData(d.SamplingRate) 
print(data.shape) 
print(data.shape[1]) 
print(data.shape[0])
        
import socket s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        
s.bind(('localhost', 1972)) # Привязываем серверный сокет к localhost и 3030 порту. 
s.listen(1) # Начинаем прослушивать входящие соединения. 
conn, addr = s.accept() # Метод который принимает входящее соединение.
        
while True:   
    data = conn.recv(1024) # Получаем данные из сокета.   
if not data:
    break   conn.sendall(data) # Отправляем данные в сокет.   print(data.decode('utf-8')) conn.close()
```

Here I have a Matlab server, my try, can you please tell me how I correctly send all data from the python side and how I receive all data from the Matlab side?

for the moment I have this:

```
t=tcpip('localhost',1972,'NetworkRole','client')
fopen(t)
while 1
        data=1:10;
        fwrite(t,data)
        end
```

Comment: Hello! It would help a lot if you could reformat your code to make it more readable. You might also want to make sure it is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on minimal). Finally you might want to make sure to do [research on your own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and show what you've tried and why it doesn't work. It seems to me that TCP communication is well documented in both languages. Hence I'm not certain where your exact problem is.

Comment: My question 1 is am I sending from python correctly? It is a continuous data
My 2nd question is how to receive data in Matlab side?

Comment: So first, I would suggest editing your question to make that clear and easier to read. Then this is a very open ended question... Unfortunately people are not here to review your code. For the first part you should be able to figure out by yourself if you're sending correctly by testing it. For the second part I would suggest for you to make a bit of research. Matlab offers [documentation on TCP clients](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tcpclient.html) with examples. Then if you still have an issue come back here and ask ONE question at a time for it helps to make better answer.

Comment: You can also visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you make better questions. Better questions will yield more and better answers. In general people on stackoverflow really expect you to put a lot of effort in your question. (Once again read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)). I think it is important to keep in mind that "[...] our time is not free, although we do not charge for it." as they state.

Comment: Why send data over TCP/IP? Are you going to have these two programs running on different computers? If not, use there are much better ways to integrate Python and MATLAB: https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-and-python.html